# Swipe-To-Dismiss in RecyclerView Produces Error

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I've a `RecyclerView` in which I've inflated `CardView`. I have a database helper named `AlarmDBHelper`. In one of my fragments, I use a button to add Alarms, which are added to the `RecyclerView` and the `Database`. Using a database viewer, I can see that the entries are added properly.

The problem is that I've added a `Swipe-To-Dismiss` using a `ItemTouchHelper`. But when I swipe to delete a cardview, the deletion isn't permanent. The `cardview` is removed but the entry in database isn't. When I move to another fragment and come back to the previous one, I can see all the cardview have showed up again. Fun part is that, this time deletion is permanent, i.e. if I swipe now, they get deleted forever.

**My AlarmDBHelper**

```
package com.aniket.digitalapprentice;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
   * Created by Aniket on 4/18/2016.
 */
public class AlarmDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME="alarmsManager";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
public static final String TABLE_ALARMS="alarms";
public static final String KEY_ID="id";
public static final String KEY_LABEL="label";
public static final String KEY_TIME="time";
public static final String KEY_DATE="date";
public SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
public SimpleDateFormat timeFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
public AlarmDBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_ALARM_TABLE="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALARMS + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_LABEL + " TEXT," + KEY_DATE+" TEXT," + KEY_TIME + " TEXT" + ")";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_ALARM_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_ALARMS);
    onCreate(db);

}
public void addAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_LABEL,alarm.getLabel());
    values.put(KEY_DATE,dateFormat.format(alarm.getDate()));
    values.put(KEY_TIME,timeFormat.format(alarm.getTime()));
    db.insert(TABLE_ALARMS,null,values);
    db.close();
}
public Alarm getAlarm(int id) throws ParseException {
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.query(TABLE_ALARMS, new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_LABEL,KEY_DATE,KEY_TIME},KEY_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor!=null) cursor.moveToFirst();
    Alarm alarm=new Alarm(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),cursor.getString(1),dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(2)),timeFormat.parse(cursor.getString(3)));
    return alarm;
}
public ArrayList<Alarm> getAllAlarms() throws ParseException {
    ArrayList<Alarm> alarmList=new ArrayList<Alarm>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALARMS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
                Alarm alarm=new Alarm(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),dateFormat.parse(cursor.getString(2)),timeFormat.parse(cursor.getString(3)));
                alarmList.add(alarm);


        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return alarmList;
}
public int getAlarmCount()
{
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_ALARMS;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return cursor.getCount();
}
public int updateAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_LABEL,alarm.getLabel());
    values.put(KEY_TIME,timeFormat.format(alarm.getTime()));
    values.put(KEY_DATE,dateFormat.format(alarm.getDate()));
    return db.update(TABLE_ALARMS,values,KEY_ID+"=?",new String[]{String.valueOf(alarm.getId())});

}
public void deleteAlarm(Alarm alarm)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_ALARMS,KEY_ID+" =? ",new String[]{String.valueOf(alarm.getId())});
    db.close();
}

}
```

**my ItemTouchHelper**

```
 ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleCallback=new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,ItemTouchHelper.LEFT|ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            int index=viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            db.deleteAlarm(alarmList1.get(index));
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"deleted "+(index),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            alarmList1.remove(index);
            alarmAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(index);
        }

    };
    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper=new ItemTouchHelper(simpleCallback);
    itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your delete function of database as:

```
public boolean deleteAlarm(int id){
  int result=db.delete(TABLE_ALARMS, KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]     {String.valueof(id)});
  if(result>0)
    return true;
  return false;
}
```

Then make remove function in your adapter class as:

```
public void remove(int pos){
  // The name of the class which is used as a helper for database to get
  // and set value suppose DatabaseHelper

  DatabaseHelper dbHelper = alarmlist.get(pos);
  int id = dbHelper.getId();

  AlarmDBHelper alarmHelper = new AlarmDBHelper(context);
  if(alarmHelper.deleteAlarm(id)){
    alarmlist.remove(pos);
  } else
    Toast.makeText(context,"Unable to delete",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    this.notifyItemRemoved(pos);

  // Now simply call the remove function in onSwiped function as:  
    onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction){
      adapter.remove(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition);
      // Here adapter is the object of the adapter class made for recyclerview
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to help you, but could you post a simple animated gif to explain more and show your situation? 
If is possible show me all the steps and actions inside your app (the exactly activities and/or fragments where occurs your issue). 
For example you can use Android Studio for creating animated gif of your android app (Android>Monitor>Screen Recorder> Start Recording). 
I hope I can help you in some way.

Comment: I solved the problem. I figured out that when I added an alarm into the database(and updating) the list, the Key value for the alarm was not updated. I implemented a program to update the key and it worked